# CSS Layout: one item overlaps the other and reaches the border of the container

Tags: html, css

Dicovered myself I can't figure out this:

[Demo link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/EjYgdP?editors=110)

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.container .small {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.container .big {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.container > div {
  height: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
</div>
```

**Question:**
How do I modify layout in a way, so that **red box** reaches the container's black border and still overlaps the **blue box.**

**Please Note:**

Content of the blue box can be vary in height, and the blue box needs to vary its height depending on the red box height (I can handle this using JS). But if there's another way using `flexbox`, will be glad to hear

**Browser support** is IE11+, FF36+, Chrome 36+, Android 4.2+, iOS 8+ so you may use almost any CSS feature you'd like.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question.

Comment: I don't really get it, isn't it `.small {left:0;}`?

Comment: @sdcr red box needs to overlay(overlap) the blue one.

Comment: @tribe84 what exactly is unclear?

Comment: How it should look, do you mean reach the left border?

Comment: @knitevision left is set to 40%, and right 60%, so no overlap. it you set left value > 40%, there will be overlap. is that the question!!??

Comment: @tribe84 yea. well it should look like in the answer below. looks like its a nice fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try zero for the left property and increasing the width of the small div.

```
.container .small {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpYwyK

This has the desired effect based on your description and the provided code.

Comment: This does not solve the variable height problem does it?

Comment: What's the height problem? The height shouldn't affect the width. It will still overlap. Are you trying to achieve something different than this in smaller viewports?

Comment: "Content of the blue box can be vary in height, and the blue box needs to vary its height depending on the red box height (I can handle this using JS). But if there's another way using flexbox, will be glad to hear"

Comment: I thought the issue was simply with the width since it was stated that the height issue can be handled. Perhaps rephrasing the question will clear that part up. The behavior of the varying height is not exactly clear to me either, as it's described. 

Does the ratio in height between both divs need to be maintained as the height of one of the divs changes?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood, as mentioned below by Opaw Nako, the left value should be 0:

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden; 

  .small {
    width: 45%;
    background-color: tomato;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    height: 350px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: none;
  }

  .big { 
    width: 60%; 
    background-color: aquamarine; 
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
  }

  > div {

  }
}
```

Setting the small box position relative, and the bigger one to absolute (contained in relative box), it will also mean the .small box will set the height that .big will follow.

Here is the [sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOomgB)

Answer (score 1):

CSS should look like this

```
.container {
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid #000;
position: relative;

.small {
width: 45%;
background-color: tomato;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
height: 250px;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
}

.big {
width: 60%;
background-color: aquamarine;
margin-left: auto;
}

> div {
height: 300px;
}
}


    Edit: You are changing the left attribute for .small from 30px to 0px. 
    And increasing the small containers width from 40% to 45% to account 
    for proper overlap.
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code does? SO doesn't just exist to answer questions but to educate people.